# Using TempData to send data from Controller to view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've been trying to get this to work; when I select the department it auto populates the employee field. Now when I send the info to the view page it doesn't show; and that only happen sometimes. I've tried using ViewBag and is the same result. Additionally viewEmployee just store data in a session so all the data entered should be shown on the other view page.

Controller-setting TempData

```
[HttpPost]
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [AcceptParameter(Name = "Add", Value = "Add")]
    public ActionResult AddItems(Employee)
    {

  IssueDAO issuedb = new IssueDAO();

TempData["ReceivedByReps"] = issuedb.SelectEmployeesByDept(employee.department)
       return View(getEmployeee);

    }


Controller

 private getEmployee 
    {
        get
        {
            Employee employee= (Employee)Session["Employee"];
            if (employee== null)
            {
                employee= new Employee();
                Session["Employee"] = employee;
            }
            return employee;

        }

    }

 public ActionResult ViewEmployee()
    {

        return View(getEmployee);
    }
```

View

```
 <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.department, new SelectList(Model.departmentsList, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "department", @class = "form-control" })
        @*@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })*@

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @*@Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeDetails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })*@
        @Html.Label("Head of Department:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        @if (Model.department == null)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        }
        else
  @Html.DropDownList("ReceivedByReps", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)TempData["ReceivedByReps"], new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    </div>
```

Other view page

```
<dt>
            @Html.Label("Head of Department:")
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.employeeDetails.getName)
        </dd>
```

Comment: Use a view model, not temp data !

Comment: @Shyju could u explain further; already have two separate views

Comment: There is nothing on your code relating to setting `TempData`

Comment: @StephenMuecke; I've updated the question

Comment: Where is that code - in which method? Its impossible to understand what your problem is.And what does _Other view page_ have to do with your question?

Comment: Because that's the other view page that would show the details; once it is sent from the controller. It is view page viewEmployee'

Comment: Also please share relevant code which can be compiled.

Comment: @Shyju; so I should use viewData

Comment: What is your expectation about this line of code `(Issue)Employee["Employee"]` ? Does your code even compile ?

Comment: Yes it compiles perfectly...and it was a mistake on my part sorry

Comment: Is just that when I send the employee name to the other view page it doesnt show sometimes...and I cant seem to figure that even after using viewBag and tempData